# Is there a way to display a bar plot and an image plotRGB in Shiny app R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, shiny

I am trying to make a shiny R app of a pokedex, I made it so when you choose the pokemon from the drop down a bar plot of its stats appear, and then I tried also adding its image using the raster plotRGB function, but Shiny only can display one plot I tried many ways to combine the bar plot and the plotRGB but it keeps giving me: **"Warning: Error in gList: only 'grobs' allowed in "gList""**

Here is my code for the ui.R:

```
shinyUI(
  pageWithSidebar(
    
    headerPanel("Shiny App Demo"),
    
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("Pokemon", "Please Select a Pokemon",
                  choices= pokemon_data$name)
      

    ),
    
    mainPanel(plotOutput("dispPlot"))
  )
  
)
```

and here is my code for the server.R:

```
shinyServer(
  
  function(input, output, session){
    
    output$dispPlot <- renderPlot({
      
      
      pokemon_name <- input$Pokemon

      
      df <- melt(as.data.table(stats_df), id.vars = "name", variable.name = "Stats",
                 value.name="Num")
      
      df<-df %>% arrange(df, name)
      
      sub <- subset(df, name == pokemon_name)
      
      stat_plot<- ggplot(sub, aes(x = Stats , y= Num, fill = Stats)) +
        geom_bar(position="dodge", stat = "identity") + xlab(paste(sub$name,"Stats"))
      

      number <- rownames(pokemon_data[pokemon_data$name == pokemon_name,])

      path <- "C:/Users/wejda/Desktop/DS_Bootcamp/Week 6/Day 29/Data/Pokemon Images Dataset/pokemon_jpg/pokemon_jpg/"
      ext <-".jpg"
      full_path <- paste0(path, number,ext)
      myJPG <- stack(full_path)
      img_plot<-plotRGB(myJPG)
      
      plot_list <- list(stat_plot,img_plot)
      grid.arrange(grobs=plot_list,ncol=length(plot_list))
      
      
      grid.newpage()
      grid.draw(rbind(stat_plot, img_plot))
      

      facet_wrap(img_plot,stat_plot)
      
    
      
    })
  }
  
)
```

Is there a way to plot both the bar and image plot together?
[This is what the pokemon image looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkiLy.png)
[This is what the bar plot looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tFWk.png)

Comment: These are the two datasets I used: 
https://www.kaggle.com/rounakbanik/pokemon
https://www.kaggle.com/kvpratama/pokemon-images-dataset